# Integral solutions of a Diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory

Find some integral solution of the equation.
$$x^2+6xy-4y^2-4x-12y-19=0$$
What is the form of integral solution?

Comment: Hint: express $x$ or $y$ as a function of the other variable, and discuss the "integrality" of the expression.

Comment: It is recommended that in addition to the statement of the problem you want help with, some context is supplied in the body of the Question.  One way to do this is by explaining your own attempt to solve it, but there are other kinds of context that help Readers respond in a way you will find useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. The equation is equivalent to
$$(x-2+3y)^2-13y^2=23.$$
We can get a solution as soon as we find $y$ such that $y^2+23$ is a perfect square. Then
$$x = -3y+2\pm\sqrt{13y^2+23}.$$
For example for $y=1$, we have $(5,1)$, $(-7,1)$, and for $y=-1$ we get $(-1,-11)$, $(11,-1)$. For $y=\pm 431$ and $y=\pm 1739$ we can obtain more solutions (they are infinite!).

Comment: Yes and very ugly general solution.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg not so bad, just two orbits..

Answer (score 2):

As $23$ is prime there are two similar linear recurrences that give all the values of $y,$ **note** that it is necessary to use both $\pm v$ form these:

In both cases of $u^2 - 13 v^2 = 23$ we get
$$ v_{n+2} = 1298 v_{n+1} - v_n   $$

$$  -1, \; 431, \; 559439, \; 726151391, $$
$$ 1, \; 1729, \; 2244241, \; 2913023089,  $$

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$  ./Pell_Target_Fundamental
  Automorphism matrix:  
    649   2340
    180   649
  Automorphism backwards:  
    649   -2340
    -180   649

  649^2 - 13 180^2 = 1

 u^2 - 13 v^2 = 23

Sun Jun  4 10:28:24 PDT 2017

u:  6  v:  1 ratio: 6  SEED   KEEP +- 
u:  1554  v:  431 ratio: 3.60557  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  6 ,  -1
u:  6234  v:  1729 ratio: 3.60555
u:  2017086  v:  559439 ratio: 3.60555
u:  8091726  v:  2244241 ratio: 3.60555

Sun Jun  4 10:29:24 PDT 2017

 u^2 - 13 v^2 = 23

jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```